# Sharing Session object and MIME message in java mail API and authentication details sharing

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

My application needs to send generated email from appointments.

Can I share Session object and MIME message in java mail API? Why it's possible or it's impossible?

Authentication details can be shared in Session and transport. Which is better?

Comment: Mail is normally HTML code. What stuffs you want to pass from Session? You can pass the values from session object to respective methods in the MIME message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.